# Установка composer пакета без Composer

Tags: php, composer

Хочу установить библиотеку https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk
Но возможности установить её через composer нет, т.к веб хостинг без доступа к ssh.
Как это можно сделать? Прошу описать все пункты как можно подробнее.

Comment: Устанавливаете на локалке, потом переносите файлы через фтп...

Comment: Всё равно хочется попробовать установить библиотеку без composer.

Comment: ну делайте без компосера, кто вам мешает? Скачиваете и пользуетесь...

Comment: Я не имею понятия как настроить его вручную.

Comment: А че его настраивать-то? скачиваете и пользуетесь) Как пользоваться на той-же странице и описано.

Comment: Проще на машине с доступом выкачать всё что нужно через composer и перенести на хостинг.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Вариант 1

Воспользоваться [сервисом](https://php-download.com/), который формирует архивный файл(.zip) из требуемого пакета, размещенного в репозитории [packagist](https://packagist.org/). Внутри архива будет находится, уже сформированный сервисом, файл `vendor/autoload.php`.

Вам нужно распаковать архив, залить его содержимое на сайт в отдельную папку и подключить его файл `/path/to/folderPackage/vendor/autoload.php` в тех скриптах, в которых планируете использовать пакет.

Информация взята из ответа на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545795/how-do-i-install-composer-php-packages-without-composer#answer-44891109)

## Вариант 2

На отдельном сервере (локальном компьютере), где установлен composer:

- создать проект - `composer init`
- добавить в проект пакет *vkcom/vk-php-sdk* - `composer require vkcom/vk-php-sdk`. Composer создаст файл autoload.php для инициализации автозагрузчика.
- перенести из созданного проекта папку `vendor` на целевой сервер, в отдельную папку (например - `vendorTwo`)
- в скриптах на целевом сервере, где планируется использовать пакет *vkcom/vk-php-sdk*, - подключить файл `require_once 'path/to/vendorTwo/autoload.php';`

Comment: "сервис" из первого варианта стал платным