# Как установить composer пакет на хостинге сайта без установленного Composer?

Tags: php, composer

Cситуация такая нахожусь на простом хостинге, установить сам composer нет возможности, скачал папку vendor.скачал с гит хаба https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk , Facebook Ads, и залил в папку на сервере в "src".Так же закинул Google, он работает нормально. А Вот Facebook.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/api/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdsInsights;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$access_token = 'указан';
$ad_account_id = 'указан';
$app_secret = 'указан';
$app_id = 'указан';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
```

При запуске ошибка 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'FacebookAds\Api' not found in
Как вылечить?

Comment: посмотрите [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965954/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-composer-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-composer/966823#966823) на похожий вопрос

Comment: ну проверьте есть ли эта папка вообще в  vendors. Если есть, то посмотрите в `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` на какую папку реально смотрит namespace `FacebookAds`. Там нет никакой магии. Если все на местах то распечатайте путь, который используется в autoload функции, там точно будет понятно где код пытается искать библиотеку. Если есть и все правильно с точки зрения путей к библиотеке, то остаются только права доступа